# buildroot with jamvm 2.0 for java 8

Tags: java, java-8, embedded-linux, buildroot, jamvm

I have a fat jar which uses java 8 features.I would like to use it with buildroot. But as I am reading on it for a couple of days, the jamvm version 2.0 supports java 8 and because of GNUClasspath limitations it we can't use any java 8.0 complaint jar's in it. Is there a way to overcome this? I also read that IcedTea can be used an alternative, but I am not sure how to install or build buildroot with IcedTea. Any pointers on this would be great.

Thanks,
G

Answer (score 2):

You could probably try with the full-featured OpenJDK, if you're using an architecture that is supported. However, there isn't yet a package for it in Buildroot.

Answer (score 0):

Also worth noting that an OpenJDK patch was submitted at: http://lists.busybox.net/pipermail/buildroot/2018-February/213282.html but it wasn't merged, I'm not sure why. Worth trying it out and possibly trying to get it merged.